# "F5", "crtl+F5" and "disable cache" didn't work for refreshing page in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, server, page-refresh

I edited and saved some content in controller file and trying to press <kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> to refresh page, it didn't work. I still have the same page.

The current way to solve the problem is to shut down the server and restart it.
I also tried DevTools' disable cache function, but it didn't work either.

Are there other ways to update page after editting controller file in MVC?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>F5</kbd>, <kbd>crtl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> and “disable cache” ensure that the client cache is cleared, but your controller action is executed on server side.

To ensure that the server application is up to date, you need to rebuild your app and you need to ensure that your server uses the updated code.

If you are using IIS (Internet Information Services), you need to recycle the corresponding app pool. If everything is properly configured this should be done automatically, since IIS should monitor the deployed files. If that doesn't happen, you may check your [FCNMode](http://imageresizing.net/docs/fcnmode).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  

I just also tried rebuilding the app by `dotnet watch run` which  can detect a file change and restart the app and it also works.